# VBA - Need to report cell format only of viewable cells after filtering

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a question about a macro in Excel VBA.
I want to get the count of colored cells in Excel, so I have written below code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
x = Range("D2:Y46").Select

For Each d In Selection 
    d.Select 
    If Selection.Interior.Color = 15773696 Then
        Count = Count + 1 
    End If 
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
Range("C53").Select 
Selection = Count
```

It is working fine, but there are some rows hidden because of heading filter.

When I am using above code, it's showing the output of hidden cells also, but I don't want the result to include the hidden cells. I need only the results for viewable cells after filter in heading.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/150363. Alternatively, you can also use `Range("D2:Y46").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code to do what you've asked for, but also improved efficiency; you don't generally ever need to `Select` a cell before doing something with it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CountCellsByColor()

Dim d As Range, x As Range
Dim Count As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set x = Range("D2:Y46")

For Each d In x
    If d.Interior.Color = 15773696 And Not d.Rows.Hidden And Not d.Columns.Hidden Then
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Range("C53").Value = Count


End Sub
```

The `Not d.Rows.Hidden` check will return `True` if the row has not been filtered out (hidden).

Comment: +1 might as well check for hidden columns as well, just in case...  If d.Interior.Color = 15773696 And Not d.Columns.Hidden And Not d.Rows.Hidden

Comment: I might mention that I tested what @Gaffi provided and first set the interior.color for the range to 15773696 programatically, but in actuality that rendered as 16763904. So if you test for the interior.color on a different machine, the code may not detect a hardcoded color correctly.

Comment: @datatoo Which is another valid point. I'm not sure what that color reference is directly, other than it's what the OP used as a color value. For my own testing, I used another color that I set and checked against at the time I wrote this answer...